# Magento 2.2.5 EE Cybersource admin order create gives message "Payment declined"?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, payment-methods

In magento2.2.5 commerce version does cyber source support admin create order feature  ? If yes do we need any more configuration in place In order to perform admin order create operation .